# Blocks in a given numeric vector

Tags: r, self-study

Given a sequence of integers:

1,1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,2,2,2,7.

It is required to report the no. of occurrences of each integer {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} but block-wise. Block-wise means an integer occurring in the sequence in non-contiguous positions should be treated in different blocks.

Required output for the given sequence:

- 1->2
- 2->1
- 3->1
- 1->1
- 3->1
- 4->1
- 5->1
- 6->1
- 2->3
- 7->1

Comment: Do you have a question? If so, can you state what it is?

Comment: try ... `?rle` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `rle()`:

```
x = c(1,1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,2,2,2,7)
(t = rle(x))
```

which returns

```
> x = c(1,1,2,3,1,3,4,5,6,2,2,2,7)
> (t = rle(x))
Run Length Encoding
 lengths: int [1:10] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1
 values : num [1:10] 1 2 3 1 3 4 5 6 2 7
```